# testing last column header of text file for equality

Tags: bash

I am trying to check if columns of a user file called `testfile.txt` are correctly named (they should be named var1, var2, var3). The file looks like

```
var1    var2    var3
5       6       7
```

I was thinking the following should work:

```
read i j k < testfile.txt

echo "${k}"

if [[ "${i}" != "var1" || "${j}" != "var2" || "${k}" != "var3" ]]; then
  echo "input incorrect"
else
  echo "input correct"
fi
```

but this returns

```
var3
input incorrect
```

So although the last column seems to be correctly named, the test fails. If I only test for the names of the first two columns, it works, but the test for the last column is always deemed false somehow.

How can I correct the script so that it can also test correctly for the value of the last column header?

Comment: Try `printf '%q\n' "$k"` instead of `echo` to show control characters, your line might end with a carriage return that gets appended to `k`.

Comment: I just tried your script and it worked fine for me

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, you are right, \r is part of $k. Is there a way to ignore these characters?

Comment: You can use `${k%$'\r'}` to refer to "variable k but without the \r at the end". However, I recommend just avoiding MS-DOS format text files altogether.

Comment: Or `dos2unix` the file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the carriage return problem. I used `sed -i 's/\r//' testfile.txt` as suggested below. That solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to strip the CR's from the header line:

```
read i j k <<< $( sed '1 s/\r//g; 2q;' testfile.txt )
```

If you want to clean the whole file:

```
tr -d "\r" <testfile.txt>x && mv x testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One in GNU awk (or any awk that supports multichar `RS` like mawk or Busybox awk):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    RS="\r?\n"                        # regard \r
    headers="var1, var2, var3"        # header names
    n=split(headers,h,/, */)          # set to an array
}
NR==1 {                               # only process first record
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # and every field of it
        if($i!=h[i] || n!=NF) {       # if a header differ of count is wrong
            print "input incorrect"   # complain
            exit                      # and leave
        }
    exit                              # leave without complaining
}' testfile
```

Output could be:

```
input incorrect
```

or not.